# How to setup the fragment shader for multiple textures on multiple objects in OpenGLES?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, textures, fragment-shader

I try to bind a texture to one object and another texture to a next object. I asked here in stackoverflow almost the same question, but the difference in that time was, that I had just one texture and multiple objects. 
[How to bind texture just to one object in OpenGLES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708452/how-to-bind-texture-just-to-one-object-in-opengles)
It worked for one texture and multiple objects, but now I have multiple textures and multiple objects. I followed the advice in the answers, but I strongly believe that this time the problem is about the fragment shader.

```
 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    synchronized (mediaPlayerObject) {
        surfaceTextureMediaPlayer.updateTexImage();
        mediaPlayeUpdate = false;
    }


    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDETEXTURE, vertexBuffer);
    vertexBuffer.position(TEXTURE_COMPONENT_COUNT);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordinatesLocation, TEXTURE_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDETEXTURE, vertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordinatesLocation);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUnitLocation2, 1);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[1]);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordinatesLocation);



    synchronized (camerObject) {
        surfaceTextureCamera.updateTexImage();
        cameraUpdate = false;
    }






    vertexBuffer2.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDETEXTURE, vertexBuffer2);
    vertexBuffer2.position(TEXTURE_COMPONENT_COUNT);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordinatesLocation, TEXTURE_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDETEXTURE, vertexBuffer2);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordinatesLocation);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUnitLocation, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordinatesLocation);
```

Here the fragment shader:

```
    #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;
uniform samplerExternalOES b_Texture;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TextureCoordinates) * texture2D(b_Texture, v_TextureCoordinates);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a second texture sampler in the fragment shader, so delete `b_Texture`. It is sufficient to bind the texture object to the texture unit and to set the index of the texture unit to the texture sampler uniform:

```c
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TextureCoordinates);
}
```

Draw 1st object:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUnitLocation, 1);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[1]);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
```

Draw 2nd object:

```java
GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUnitLocation, 0);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
```

Note, it is not necessary to use 2 different texture units. You can use `GL_TEXTURE0` in both cases.

Comment: thank you, sir. It works. For all those who struggle the same - check if you are loading correctly the textures.